# Deleting a single product from a session array (Laravel sessions & PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, session, mollie

i'm currently working on a webshop that's all about different types of hair colors, but i kinda have an issue right now. I'm working on a button that automatically deletes one product from a session file. For that i'm using a `$request->session()->forget('cart');` line.

This is what my controller looks like:

```
public function index()
{
    // Dit zorgt ervoor dat alle producten in het tabel Product-
    // opgehaald worden en in de variabele $products gezet worden

    $products = Product::all();

    return view('winkelmand', compact('products'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function create()
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return Application|Factory|View
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::find($request->id);
    if (!$product) {
        abort(404);
    }
    $id = $request->id;

    $cart = session()->get('cart');
    // Als het winkelwagendje leeg is, dan is dit het eerste product
    if (!$cart) {
        $cart = [
            $id => [
                "name" => $product->name,
                "description" => $product->description,
                "price" => $product->price,
                "quantity" => 1
            ]
        ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return view('winkelmand');
    }

    // Als het product al bestaat, dan de quantiteit verhogen met 1
    if (isset($cart[$id])) {
        $cart[$id]['quantity']++;
        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return view('winkelmand');
    }
    // Als het product niet bestaat dan toevoegen met quantiteit = 1
    $cart[$id] = [
        "name" => $product->name,
        "price" => $product->price,
        "description" => $product->description,
        "quantity" => 1
    ];

    session()->put('cart', $cart);

    return view('winkelmand');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 * @param int $id
 * @return Application|Factory|View
 */
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    return false;
}


/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    return false;
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * //     * @param int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->id && $request->quantity) {
        $cart = session()->get('cart');

        $cart[$request->id]["quantity"] = $request->quantity;

        session()->put('cart', $cart);
        session()->flash('success', 'Cart updated successfully');
    }
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * //     * @param int $id
 * @return string
 */
public function destroy(Request $request)
{
    //Deze functie moet ervoor zorgen dat er door middel van een knop de
    // desbetreffende item verwijderd wordt uit het winkelwagentje.
    // Deze functie werkt alleen nog niet en wordt dus niet gebruikt in de webshop

    $request->session()->forget('cart');
    dd('cart');

    return view('winkelmand');
}
```

I added a button using a form and method `POST` to the HTML:

```html
<td>
    <form action="/winkelmand/{{ $id }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" />
        <input type="submit" value="x" />
    </form>
</td>
```

So it's supposed to retrieve one specific product from the session (from whatever product button is pressed) and then it's supposed to forget that key from a session.

Anybody who can help me with that?

Ps. Sorry for my vocabulary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never shared what the issue is. Is it not working ? Based on your code, I am assuming you are getting perma `404`.

Some tips:

- No need to do `abort(404)`, you can directly use `findOrFail($request->id)`.
- No need to do `findOrFail` when you can take advantage of [Implicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#implicit-binding).
- No need to write `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete" />`, you can directly do [`@method('DELETE')`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#method-field).

I assume your problem is that you are using `$request->id` but you are never sending `id`. You have `id` in the URL, but for your code to work, you should do:

```php
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return Application|Factory|View
 */
public function store(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
```

Remember to replace this part of the code with mine above:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $product = Product::find($request->id);
    if (!$product) {
        abort(404);
    }
    $id = $request->id;
```

---

This still looks for the product to exists (no random `id`s). Then get the `cart`, find if the `id` exists in that `cart` and `unset` it (delete it), save the `cart` again, and done.

```php
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{
    Product::findOrFail($id);

    $cart = session()->get('cart');

    if (isset($cart[$id])) {
        unset($cart[$id]);

        session()->put('cart', $cart);
    }

    return view('winkelmand');
}
```

Comment: Well, i want to request the session array and then delete the specific product of which button is pressed. And i might need to specify by id to get that to work.

I'm using $request->session()->forget('cart'); to remove it from the session, but this deletes the entire array.

So i need a little help here because i'm not able to request the session array and delete ONE specific product whenever i press the 'delete' button

Comment: If you want to do that, you should get the `cart` from the session, directly remove the `id` from the `$cart`, and then store the `$cart` again in the session replacing the old one.

Comment: So you're saying that i should remove id from the variable $cart and then like "refresh" the session. Is there any sort of code that lets me do that?

Comment: @RickMondria your code is correct, except the part I changed in my answer, you change it how I did, and it should work as intended ! (Remember to delete `$id = $request->id`). See my answer (I edited it).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I changed it too what you commented and now i'm getting this error:
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\CartController::store(), 1 passed in D:\PhpstormProjects\my-webshop-1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54 and exactly 2 expected.

the public function now has a blank $request and it says it's not being used

Comment: @RickMondria Oh, so you are not using the same URL as `delete` right, but with `delete` instead of `post`. Can you share your routes please ?

Comment: `Route::resource('/winkelmand', CartController::class);` is the route i use. My CartController is a resourcecontroller, which made the functions for me. Other routes i use are: 

`Route::resource('/producten', ProductController::class);`

and 

`Route::get('/pay', [PaymentController::class, 'preparePayment']);`

Comment: Wait, so, the `HTML` (`Blade`) you shared is pointing to the `destroy` method. I helped you with the `store` method. What help do you need with the `destroy` method ?

Comment: Well i'm directing you to the `destroy` function because i need help with the button that makes sure that i delet one product from a Laravel session file. I included the whole controller, not one function (which you probably thought was `store`.
I'm using the ``()forget method that removes a key from the session file, but i've only set it to 'cart' just to check if that method works. Now i'm trying to find a solution to delete one product from that session file so that's why i need some help. My teacher said that i should request that session and then pick out the specific product.

Comment: @RickMondria my bad about that, see my updated answer. If you still only have `cart` as a session id and then you have to find the `id` inside `cart`, my code will do it for you. Please, tell me if you are looking for that, else what else can I add or what am I missing ?

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. It's working as intended. Thank you so much for helping me out!